# Заменить двойные слеши в URL

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Допустим имею такой URL:

```
ptc-serv://regex101.com//path//post?p="z//"
```

...в конце `?p="z//"`

Как на JS заменить двойные слеши(на один `/`) не затрагивая символы после `?` и `#`,
и соответственно первые два после протокола `http://`.

Пример https://regex101.com/r/vnRU0Z/1

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**UPD** - поправлю вопрос. Надо чтоб осталось:

```
ptc-serv://regex101.com/path/post?p="z//"
```

Comment: Может, https://regex101.com/r/gs1YQu/1 ?

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew, поправил вопрос - что должно остаться.

Comment: `s.replace(/(^\w[\w-]*:\/\/|"[^"]*")|(\/)+/g, '$1$2')`? https://regex101.com/r/ECbhUy/1

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew, вот странное дело - не получается у меня вывести группами, потому как проверку на протокол я пишу не так `\w[\w-]*`, а так `\w(\-\w+)?` - дефис может быть только в центре, и соответственно появляются скобки и еще одна группа. Сначала и думал группами выводить.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew, с группами напутал, если проверять так `\w+(\-\w+)?`, надо было `$1$3`

Comment: Используйте незахватывающие подмаски: `\w(\-\w+)?` => `\w(?:-\w+)?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если в адресе кроме протокола двоеточий перед слешами нет (по крайней мере до `#` и `?`):

```js
console.log(
  'ptc-serv://regex101.com//path//post?p="z//"'.replace(/(:\/\/|[#?].*)|(\/)\//g, "$1$2")
)
```

Comment: Да, наверное это единственное что можно сделать, только немного изменил `/(^\w+(\-\w+)?\:\/{2}|[#?].*)|(\/)\/+/g`. Додумал еще один способ, но выражение длиннее и выполняется дольше `'p-s://reg.c//p-s:///t?p="z//"'.replace( /((?<!^(\w+(\-\w+)?\:))(?<=^[^?#]+))\/{2,}/g, '/' )`.

Comment: @AlexanderLonberg, можно `(\/)\/+` заменить на `(\/)+`.

Answer (score 1):

```js
console.log(
  'ptc-serv://regex101.com//path//post?p="z//"'
    .replace(/(:\/\/)([^#?]*)/, (m,l,u) => l + u.replace(/\/\//g, "/"))
)
```